# HandleBars having an issue with calling a function

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

```
 <div class="err">
{{#if error}}
    <script>warning({{error}})</script>
{{/if}}
</div>
<h1>Login</h1>
<form method="post" action="/">
    <input ype="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" value={{data.name}}>
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" value= 
    {{data.username}}>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" value= 
   {{data.password}}>
    <input type="password" name="password2" placeholder="Confirm password" 
    value={{data.password2}}>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>`
```

This is my login file when an error is passed to hbs file it has to call an function which is in public directory I have linked all the scripts files...
**Problem:** 
       when a function is called i should pass the value the error value to the function but i donno how to write and ended up wasting my entire day with this thing please help me out...